# How to calculate 2-D confidence intervals with the boot package in R?

Tags: confidence-interval, inference, bootstrap, resampling

I'm making a scatter plot of two statistics X(e) and Y(e) for various values of scalar parameter e. The sampling distribution of both X and Y is not normally distributed.

Now I want to calculate a 2-D 95% confidence interval/region for each point (X(e),Y(e)) in the scatter plot. How can I do that?

Since the sampling distribution is not normally distributed I'm using the boot package in R. Which works for calculating 95% confidence intervals for X(e) and Y(e) independently. Is it possible to use this package to generate a 95% confidence region?